# Rails has_many where associated record meets a criteria

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In this (simplified) system,

```
class Order
  has_one :bill
  ...
end


class Bill
  has_many :rebills
  belongs_to :order

  ...
end

class Rebill
  belongs_to :bill
  ...
end
```

Both `Bill` and `Rebill` have a `status` column that could be in one of a variety of states, some the equate to success and some that equate to failure.

I am currently trying to find all the `Order` records that don't have some kind of successful payment. An order meets my criteria if the associated `Bill` record is in a failed state, and that `Bill` records have *no* associated `Rebill` records that are in a *successful* state.

If an `Order` has a `Bill` that failed, a `Rebill` that also failed, and a second `Rebill` that succeeded, then the `Order` has been paid, and I'm not interested in it.

If an `Order` has a `Bill` that failed and no associated `Rebills`, then it has no successful payment and I *am* interested in it.

If an `Order` has a `Bill` that failed, and any number of `Rebills` in a failed state (but not one in a successful state) then there is no successful payment and I *am* interested in it.

My question, therefore, is how to construct a query that returns all `Order` records that do not have some kind of successful payment? The real issue here is that I'm holding the notion of a successful payment in multiple places, which is bad. However, I feel like I should be able to whisper the correct SQL incantation to do this, but the number of join's, where's, having's and count's is confusing me beyond belief!

Anyone have any clue what I'm trying to do here, and if so any inkling of how I might do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that complicated. First of all, let's find all `Order` records that have a `Bill` record in a failed state.

```
Order.joins(:bill).where(bills: { state: "failed" })
```

Now let's make sure that for the `Bill`, there exists no `Rebill` in a successful state:

```
Order.joins(:bill).where(bills: { state: "failed" })
     .where("NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM rebills 
                        WHERE bill_id = bills.id 
                        AND rebills.state = successful)")
```

You may be able to write the `NOT EXISTS` query in a more ActiveRecord way, I usually give up and go for raw SQL.

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3d8b676841cca8361abdee57bb078cd0) attached.

Comment: I think you might be missing the closing parens for `EXISTS(`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job.

```ruby
# rebills contains all rebills with a successful payment
rebills = Rebill.where(status: 'successful')
# bills contains bills without a successful payment
# that are not associated with the above described rebills 
bills = Bill.where.not(status: 'successful', id: rebills.select(:bill_id))
# orders contains orders that are associated with the above described bills
orders = Order.where(id: bills.select(:order_id))
```

The above should execute a single query when `orders` is loaded.

**Note:** When copied into the console suffix the lines with `;nil` to prevent the *inspect* method (which is used to show the console return value) to load the collections.